# No zlib.h file in usr/local/include how to get it

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zlib

so I have been trying to run a C++ program which requires Zlib library on compiling the file it gave an error saying "zlib.h no such file or directory exists" upon looking in usr/local/include i found that the file is not there can i just copy the file to that location or should i Install some thing. i am kinda new to ubuntu so please help

Comment: Question and answer was also useful when installing/building Swift Vapor on Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Install `zlib` with development support by using

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

In case you don't want or need to use the full `zlib`, it is fairly easy to write wrapper routines which map the `zlib` functions 1:1 to ordinary file functions which don't support compression and decompression.

```
//
//  dummy zlib.h
//

#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

typedef FILE *gzFile;

int gzclose(gzFile file);
gzFile gzdopen(int fd, const char *mode);
gzFile gzopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
int gzread(gzFile file, void *buf, unsigned int len);


//
//  zlibDummy.cpp
//

#include <zlib.h>

int gzclose(gzFile file)
{
    return fclose(file);
}

gzFile gzdopen(int fd, const char *mode)
{
    return _fdopen(fd, mode);
}

gzFile gzopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    return fopen(path, mode);
}

int gzread(gzFile file, void *buf, unsigned int len)
{
    return fread(buf, 1, len, file);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, temporary solution

download from : https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h
put the file in the same folder as your project file.

```
#include "zlib.h"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i think it will work but Axel's was better

Comment: It's a little risky just installing zlib.h unless you are sure that it corresponds to the installed library that you'll be linking to.  It's safer to do an apt-get, yum, brew, or whatever package manager your system uses, to install both libz and zlib.h.

Comment: I wrote this answer as a quick way to go ahead with the development. Though i would never recommend doing it. And i probably would not do it too.